# How to accumulate sum in each indexed element in loop[python]?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The loop goes through list of numbers. I need to use map to accumulate the sum of all element[0] in another list's element[0] , sum of all element[1] in element[1].

```
result_list = []
sub1 = sub2 = sub3 = 0 #these 3 should be only indexes 0,1,2 of list above
for item in r:        
    l = item.split(';') # originally l = '34;56;78'
    q = list(map(float,l)) # q is the list of  3 elements

    #instead of code below I want to have smth like
    # result_list = list(map( sum( q(item), result_list)
    sub1 += q[0]
    sub2 += q[1]
    sub3 += q[2]
```

Input:

```
l = [['1;2;3'], ['10;20;30'], ['12;34;56']]
```

result_list must aggregate the sum of all element[0] in each list to result_list[0].
Output

```
result_list[0] = 1+ 10 + 12 
result_list[1] = 2 + 20 + 34
result_list[2] = 3 + 30 + 56
```

r is this, I omit names and calculate average of each 'column'.

```
Bawerman;55;79;50
Baldwin;83;62;72
Owen;94;86;65
Watson;92;79;100
Clifford;33;99;47
Murphy;94;87;53
Shorter;83;61;61
Bishop;27;89;41
```

Comment: Please add input, expected output pairs

Comment: can you give some indication as to what `r` is?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, done sir, pls take a look

Comment: @James, r is 2d array or array of strings, I process each string

Comment: Does the inner elements of l are lists?

Comment: Please, provide `r`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo, yes sir , they are lists, pls take a look at the input i included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
l = [["1;2;3"], ["10;20;30"], ["12;34;56"]]
result_list = []

l = [list(map(float, j.split(";"))) for i in l for j in i]
for i in zip(*l):
    result_list.append(sum(i))
print(result_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[23.0, 56.0, 89.0]
```

Comment: for i in l for j in i - do u need comma after l? i dont understand this piece of code

Comment: No you do not need a comma. It is a nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

A oneliner can do the job:

If you need first to parse the strings with the numbers:

```
l = [[int(i) for i in e[0].split(';')] for e in l]
```

And after that, just:

```
result = map(sum, zip(*l))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, assuming each element of `l` is a list of one string:

```
l = [['1;2;3'], ['10;20;30'], ['12;34;56']]
numbers = (map(float, e.split(';')) for e, in l)
result = [sum(n) for n in zip(*numbers)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[23.0, 56.0, 89.0]
```

Comment: thank u , but there is bug no? or typo? "for e, in l" - do u need comma?

Comment: Yes, to unpack the elements

Answer (score 1):

#### [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) + [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

> I omit names and calculate average of each 'column'

You don't need to construct a large list of lists from your data. You can use an iterator and use sequence unpacking with `zip`. To calculate the mean, you can use `statistics.mean`:

```
from io import StringIO
from statistics import mean
import csv

x = StringIO("""Bawerman;55;79;50
Baldwin;83;62;72
Owen;94;86;65
Watson;92;79;100
Clifford;33;99;47
Murphy;94;87;53
Shorter;83;61;61
Bishop;27;89;41""")

# replace x with open('file.csv', 'r')
with x as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(x, delimiter=';')
    zipper = zip(*reader)
    next(zipper)  # ignore labels
    res = [mean(map(float, x)) for x in zipper]

print(res)

# [70.125, 80.25, 61.125]
```